# Can SQL-Adapter handle transaction(begin/insert/roolback)?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Worklight Studio v6.2
MySQL Community Server 5.6.21

I did simple experiment for this.
I created 4 procedures in a sql adapter.

"begin" procedure, which invokes just "BEGIN;" statement.
"commit" procedure, which  invokes just "COMMIT;" statement.
"rollback" procedure, which  invokes just "ROLLBACK;" statement.
"insert" procedure, which  invokes "INSERT" statement which insert a row to a table.

In addtion,I created hybrid app which has buttons. Each button executes the procedure above.

I opened it by browser for test.
I execute "begin -> insert -> commit" and "begin -> insert -> rollback". Both work fine.

Next, I opend the application from two browsers(A/B). And I execute below.

1.From browser A:begin
2.From browser A:insert
3.From browser **B**:commit

It is **committed**. 
The database can not distinguish that each request comes from diffrent user by this way.
Any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update:* What you could try is:

1. Make your code more atomic, in the sense that instead of 4 procedures, make all of these various calls in 1 procedure, **or**
2. Unique-ify your SQL query, by sending with it a unique identifier ... this way there shouldn't be any mixing between browsers' sessions. You will need to verify that you are operating on this unique identifier.

---

*Edit: this is not the correct soution, as connectAs="endUser" is not supported in SQL adapeders*

I ***think*** what you need to do is add the `connectAs="endUser"` attribute to the adapter procedures in the in the adapter XML file: `<procedure name="myProcedure" connectAs="endUser"/>`.

From this following blog post, which you should read, `connectAs="endUser"` means:

> In order to support stateful backend HTTP adapter procedures can be
>   configured to work in a connectAs=“endUser” mode. This mode means that
>   a separate instance of HTTP session will be created for each client
>   session

Blog post: [Configuring HTTP adapters for stateless/stateful backend connectivity and user identity propagation](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/configuring_http_adapters_for_stateless_stateful_backend_connectivity_and_user_identity_propagation?lang=en)

Comment: Thanks, Idan. I added 'SecrutyTest' and 'connectAs="endUser"' attributes for my precedures, and tested it. But results are same. It says "[WARNING ] FWLSE0195W: Ignoring connectAs attribute of procedure beginprocedure in adapter testSQL. ConnectAs is not supported by this adapter type. ". Can I use connectAs="endUser" attribute in sql adapter?

Comment: Ah, indeed you're right - connectAs is not supported in SQL adapters; what you could try is perhaps send a userId parameter with your SQL procedure to make SQL aware of this so that the invocations will be specific to a single user.